# JAVA: RMI Callback -> object already exported

Tags: java, callback, server, rmi, stub

this is my first question, so sorry if i'll make it incorrect and for my english.

I have to do a distributed-hangman project in java, there are guests, players and masters (more matches). When a user(already registered) log himself or when a master open a match, the server must notifies to all guests (only guests) the event.
In the client i had to create 2 stub, 1 for the server, the other one for the graphic interface (swing).

The threadpool is for manage the matches, not used now. 
This is the client code:

```java
package User;

public class Utente extends RemoteServer implements UserInterface, GraphicInterface,Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;
private String name;
private String password;
private String host = "localhost";
private Socket soc;
private int port = 1800;
private UserInterface stub = null;
private RegistryInterface server_interface = null;
private Registry server_registry;


public Utente(){
    super();
    this.name = "user";
    this.password = "passwd";
    //per connettersi al server
    try {
        server_registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(host);
        server_interface = (RegistryInterface)server_registry.lookup("HANGMAN-SERVER");
    } catch (RemoteException | NotBoundException e) {
        System.out.println("errore connessione lato client");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //per l' rmi con la gui

}


public synchronized boolean login(String n, String p) throws RemoteException {
    boolean esito = false;
    export();
    esito = server_interface.login(n,p,stub);
    return esito;
}

public synchronized boolean logout() throws RemoteException {
    boolean esito = false;
    esito = server_interface.logout(name,stub);
    return esito;
}

public synchronized void notifyMatch(ArrayList<Partita> lista_partite) throws RemoteException {
    if(lista_partite!=null){
        if(lista_partite.size()==0){
            System.out.println("Ancora nessuna partita aperta.");
        }
        else{
            for(int i = 0;i<lista_partite.size();i++){
            System.out.println(lista_partite.get(i).getNameMatch());
            }
        }
    }
}

public void connect(){
    try {
        soc = new Socket(host, port);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Utente user = new Utente();
    Registry c;
    GraphicInterface stubExport = null;
    try{
        stubExport = (GraphicInterface)UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(user,3900);
        LocateRegistry.createRegistry(5000);
        c=LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
        c.rebind("GraphicUI", stubExport);
    }
    catch (RemoteException e) {
        System.out.println("errore nel client: " + e.toString());
    }
    MainPanel startPanel = new MainPanel();
    startPanel.setVisible(true);    
}



}
```

Errors list:

```
UI export problems
java.rmi.server.ExportException: object already exported
    at sun.rmi.transport.ObjectTable.putTarget(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.exportObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.exportObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.exportObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.LiveRef.exportObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(Unknown Source)
    at User.Utente.export(Utente.java:59)
    at User.Utente.login(Utente.java:100)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$254(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$$Lambda$1/1989325584.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at registry.Server.callbackClient(Server.java:189)
    at registry.Server.login(Server.java:201)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$254(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$$Lambda$1/1786588690.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.login(Unknown Source)
    at User.Utente.login(Utente.java:101)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$254(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$$Lambda$1/1989325584.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.login(Unknown Source)
    at gui.MainPanel$2.actionPerformed(MainPanel.java:110)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Thank you for your patience, i hope the question is well formed. The code is ugly i know, not much time and i changed it a lot.

Comment: Check 59th and 100th line of code in class Utente.java as shown in the exception :-  `Utente.java:59, Utente.login(Utente.java:100)` !

Comment: Have your client extend `UnicastRemoteObject` and get rid of *both* `exportObject` calls.

Comment: You're really expected to be able to sort your own null pointer exceptions. Obviously `server_interface` is null.

Comment: **Don't** edit your question to turn it into a completely new one, especially when you retain the old title. Ask a new question.

Comment: i thought to it later, but i thought also is not good "allocate" a new similar question. Hwe i remember it for the next time

Comment: It's not a similar question. It's a complete difference question. This one has been answered, twice, and you've accepted an answer. It's done. Over. Dusted. Finito.

Comment: Keep calm.It was my first question, i understood i did a wrong thing editing the question also by myself (infact counter for good question went down).

Comment: sorry need to edit the code to remove it

Comment: Re your now deleted non-answer "I export twice cause i need a stub for the UserInterface(callback beetween server and client) and one for the GraphicInterface(rmi between client and gui)": you don't need two stub objects and you *cannot* export twice, as the error message clearly indicates. You can use the same stub object for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, I guess I have found the error in your `Utente` class. You have exported your object at 2 places in your code, which results in `java.rmi.server.ExportException:object already exported.`

In your Utente's main() method, you have

```
stubExport = (GraphicInterface)UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(user,3900);
```

where **`user`** is an object of class Utente.

Also, in the same class' login() method, you are calling export() method, which contains :-

```
stub = (UserInterface) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(this,0);
```

Here, `this` would pertain to Utente's currently calling object, which would be **`user`** in that case, which has already been exported earlier.

Hence, it seems you're exporting the object twice, resulting in the thrown exception.

Please reply whether this helped or not. Good Luck!

Comment: i thought to one solution to use just one interface, so no need two stub. I'll tell you next days if it works

Comment: it' s a partial solution. Without GUI everything works properly, the problem comes when i try to use it. I edit my answer  with new code, one moment

Comment: @ghiltanas- As [EJP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/207421/ejp) suggested in the comments to the question, we can't help you with your null-pointer exceptions.. That's flaw in your GUI code,not in your RMI. This answer resolves what you asked, and hence, this answer is perfect explanation for your error. Let the answer be accepted for future visits. Good luck to you for resolving the next error.